# spring mvc forms: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'destination'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I got this error : "org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag.doStartTag Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'destination' available as request attribute" and I don't understand why.

Here is my form:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="destination" action="itineraire">
                        <spring:bind path="depart">
                            <form:label path="depart">Destination de départ</form:label>
                            <form:input path="depart" />
                        </spring:bind>
                        <spring:bind path="arrive">
                            <form:label path="arrive">Destination d'arrivé</form:label>
                            <form:input path="arrive" />
                        </spring:bind>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-new"  value="itineraire">Rechercher</button>
                    </form:form>
```

Here my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {
    ArrayList<Station> stationArray = new ArrayList<>();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStations(Model model){
        try{
            URI uri = new URI("https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/idecycle");
            JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(uri.toURL().openStream());
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
            JSONArray stations = root.getJSONObject("network").getJSONArray("stations");
            int nbStation = stations.length();

            if (stationArray.size() != nbStation) {
                for (int i = 0; i < nbStation; i++) {
                    String name = (String) stations.getJSONObject(i).get("name");
                    int freeBikes = (int) stations.getJSONObject(i).get("free_bikes");
                    double lat = (double) stations.getJSONObject(i).get("latitude");
                    double lng = (double) stations.getJSONObject(i).get("longitude");
                    Position position = new Position(lat, lng);
                    Station station = new Station(name,position, freeBikes);
                    stationArray.add(station);
                }
            }


            return "accueil";
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "accueil";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/itineraire",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String shorterWay(@ModelAttribute("destination") Destination destination,BindingResult result, Model model){
        try{
            int res = GoogleMapFunction.shorterStation(stationArray,"28+rue+Ronsard+64000");
            System.out.println(stationArray.get(res));
            int res2 = GoogleMapFunction.shorterStation(stationArray,"Pau");
            System.out.println(stationArray.get(res2));
            model.addAttribute("res1", res );
            model.addAttribute("res2", res2 );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "accueil";
    }
}
```

Here my model:

```
public class Destination {
    String depart;
    String arrive;

    public Destination(String depart) {
        this.depart = depart;
    }

    public Destination(String depart, String arrive) {
        this.depart = depart;
        this.arrive = arrive;
    }

    public String getDepart() {
        return depart;
    }

    public void setDepart(String depart) {
        this.depart = depart;
    }

    public String getArrivé() {
        return arrive;
    }

    public void setArrivé(String arrivé) {
        this.arrive = arrivé;
    }
}
```

If someone can help me, I just want to get values send from my form. I already have check other answer but none help me..

Comment: Have you read the stack trace? You aren't putting anything in the model in your GET method. So no model with that name is available (which is exactly what the error is telling you).

Comment: Yes I read the trace, I forget to put my model destination. I will edit my post

Comment: Read my comment... I wasn't talking about missing code... In your GET method you put nothing in de `Model`!

Comment: Hmmm, it's true, but I need nothing in my model in my get method. Or I haven't understand the problem. it's works when I delete the code of my forms. I don't use my model in my get method

Comment: No you are using it in your form, hence yo need to prepare the model correctly...

Comment: Hmmm I don't see what I have to do ( sorry I'm newbie with jee and spring )

Comment: `model.addObject("destination", new Destination());`.